# react native text breaks word in the middle

Tags: css, react-native, line-breaks, word-break

I show text in a react native Text component, within several, nested View components.
I retrieve this text from a service, that I call.
The text varies per call.
In some cases, react native (both iOS and android) automatically breaks the text, in the middle of a word.
example: i have a d
og


how can I force react native to keep words together / to only do a line-break between words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we found a solution: we filter out non-breaking spaces in the front end.
we don't know how/where the spaces in our content (imported into our database and retrieved in the front end using a backend service) are converted to non-breaking spaces.

Answer (score 0):

> To Break the Text

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
   Hello This is an example of 
   {'\n'}
   multiline text
</Text>
  <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{`Here is an other way to 
     set multiline text.`}</Text>
 </View>
```

Comment: thanks, saroj, but placing a \n in the text is not possible, because the text is variable and comes from the backend

Comment: your second solution is for setting multiline text? react native already shows my text(s) in multiple lines. that is not the problem.

Comment: @tommer you can use css property ; word-wrap: wrap;

Comment: i put your suggestion at the bottom of my .js file within const styles = StyleSheet.create({
, but i get a syntax error. When i change it to wordWrap, i get an Invariant violation...